# Find function by solving equations and imposing constraints

Tags: equation-solving, fitting

Suppose there are two equations:

$$2f(x)+x^2g(x)=8 \tag{1},$$

$$ x^3f(x)+6g(x)=18 \tag{2}.$$

I need to solve these two equations and find the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in terms of $x$ and constants. The constraints for the functions are:

$$\begin{align*}f(0) &= 9.5,\\
g(0) &= 49,\\
f(x) &\sim 5x \quad (\text{as } x\to\infty),\\
g(x) &\sim 3/x \quad (\text{as } x\to\infty).\end{align*}$$

Is it possible to find such functions with *Mathematica*?

Comment: **and at x tends to infinity, f(x)=5x and g(x)=3/x.** what does this actually mean? since when x is infinity, then 5*x is also infinity and 3/x is zero when x is infinity.  But why not just solve the equations for `f` and `g`. There can be either one unique solution, or no solution, or infinite number of solutions,. These are the only possible outcomes.

Comment: Not exactly at infinity, when x is very large then the behavior of f(x) and g(x) are given. It is a sample problem, maybe analytically possible. The real issue is much more complicated but follows the same argument.

Comment: `{{f[x] -> (6 (-8 + 3 x^2))/(-12 + x^5),   g[x] -> (4 (-9 + 2 x^3))/(-12 + x^5)}}`are the only possible solutions.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you. If you please provide the necessary codes to solve equations and find functions that also fit the given conditions, will be helpful.

Comment: I gave the possible solutions. You can not specify conditions that are incompatible with these solutions. E.g. f[0]==4 and not 9.5

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps a bit more compact solution (than @user64494's answer)  using `Asymptotics` (I changed parameter name `f` to `ff` to avoid conflict with function name `f[x]`)

```
solfg = solfg = Solve[{x^3*f[x] + 6*g[x] == 18*(a*x^4 + b) ,2*f[x] + x^2*g[x] == 8*(c*x + ff)}, {f[x], g[x]}][[1]]

eqnf = Assuming[Element[{a, b, c, ff},Reals], {
Asymptotic[f[x] /. solfg, x -> 0] == 19/2 , 
Asymptotic[f[x] /. solfg, x -> Infinity] == 5 x }];     

eqng = Assuming[Element[{a, b, c, ff},Reals], {
Asymptotic[g[x] /. solfg, x -> 0] == 49 , 
Asymptotic[g[x] /. solfg, x -> Infinity] == 3/x }];

sol = SolveAlways[Join[eqnf, eqng], x]
(*{{a -> 5/18, b -> 49/3, c -> 13/8, ff -> 19/8}}*)


solfg/.sol 
(*{{f[x] -> (6 (-19 - 13 x + 49 x^2 + (5 x^6)/6))/(-12 + x^5), 
g[x] -> -((4 (147 - (19 x^3)/4 - (3 x^4)/4))/(-12 + x^5))}}*)
```

$\left\{\left\{f(x)\to \frac{6 \left(\frac{5 x^6}{6}+49 x^2-13x-19\right)}{x^5-12},g(x)\to -\frac{4 \left(-\frac{3x^4}{4}-\frac{19 x^3}{4}+147\right)}{x^5-12}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: Isn't your answer a slight improvement of my answer submitted two hours before yours? I expect you'll notice it.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your .............. and question, you want to choose the RHSes of (1) and (2) s.t."Where f(x) and g(x) fits as, at x=0, f(x)=9.5, g(x)=49 and at x tends to infinity, f(x)=5x and g(x)=3/x" holds. This can be done by hand with  help of Mathematica as follows.

```
sol = Solve[x^3*f[x] + 6*g[x] == 18*(a*x^4 + b) && 
2*f[x] + x^2*g[x] == 8*(c*x + f), {f[x], g[x]}]
```

> `{{f[x] -> (6 (-8 f - 8 c x + 3 b x^2 + 3 a x^6))/(-12 + x^5),  g[x] -> -((4 (9 b - 2 f x^3 + 9 a x^4 - 2 c x^4))/(-12 + x^5))}}`

Now the result of

```
sol /. {x -> 0}
```

> `{{f[0] -> 4 f, g[0] -> 3 b}}`

implies `f==9.5/4` and `b==49/3`. Next,

```
Series[f[x] /. sol, {x, Infinity, 1}]
```

> `{18 a x+O[1/x]^2}`

implies `a==5/18` and then

```
Series[(g[x] /. sol) /. a -> 5/18, {x, Infinity, 1}]
```

> `{(2 (-5+4 c))/x+O[1/x]^2}`

implies `c==13/8`.

Comment: user64494 Thank you very much for your answer. I'm sorry for the confusion created by .................., it is only assigning the equations with equation numbers. It is not the fill-in-the-blank type sign. It is not clear to me why you use ax^4+b in RHS.

Comment: @PabitraTripathy: I tried to satisfy your conditions.

Comment: I see, you modified equations to satisfy the constraints. But the problem is a bit different, we have two equations of functions and a set of constraints, and we need to know the explicit form of the functions. Thanks for your efforts.